# Jenkins service unavailable error - 503 - running as different user

Tags: git, jenkins

I am having a git repository which is restricted to my team and i want to set up jenkins in my system. Since jenkins runs as jenkins user, I am working on running jenkins as me. I followed the steps from http://blog.manula.org/2013/03/running-jenkins-under-different-user-in.html but after this when i start jenkins I am getting Service unavailable error 503.
Its because i changed user in /etc/default/jenkins to my id from jenkins. When i change it back to jenkins it works.
There is no log in /var/log/jenkins/..Has anyone faced this issue before?.

Answer (score 9):

I find out the directory owner of `/var/cache/jenkins` and `/var/lib/jenkins` somehow be changed back to **jenkins**, just redo

`sudo chown YOUR_USER_NAME /var/lib/jenkins`

`sudo chown YOUR_USER_NAME /var/cache/jenkins`

Restart jenkins, it should work.

Also check /var/log/jenkins if the same problem shows there.

Comment: Helped me in fixing the same issue.

Comment: Just to add to the answer, `chown -R` might help, if you are having any further issues.